# Were there cockroaches on the ark?

Tags: parashat-noach, bugs, mabul

I am interested to know if there were cockroaches on Noah's ark?

I was asked this question by someone and didn't have the answer.

Answer (score 11):

Great question!

Apparently, 2 cockroaches were on the ark. [Breishit (Gen.) 6:20](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14020&st=&pgnum=113) mentions "all that crawls on the land". I would include insects in that category.

Apparently, they made it out of the ark alive, too as [Breishit 8:17](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14020&st=&pgnum=127) implies. Miraculous that the elephants didn't squash them and the cats didn't eat them :-)

Comment: Rashi seems to be saying that each species was in its own cage.